# Height for parent based on child with fixed ratio

Tags: css, video, aspect-ratio, calc

Maybe there's another way round but no JavaScript. I've rebuilt my situation to show you. I need to set the max-height for ".flex" (the green one) to the height of my video with a ratio of 16/9. The containers surrounding  the video contain a variable amount of content and I want to have them the same height as the player because it is relevant content for the player.

I'm not able to change the structure so this is how it is. I would prefer a CSS only solution.

```
.flex {
   max-height: calc(WHAT IS MY HEIGHT??); 
}
```

https://codepen.io/bbua97/pen/RwYMqJy

EDIT:

I didn't make it clear enough. Both containers surrounding the video will contain a undefined amount of list items with fixed height. So in order to get a scroll bar there, I need to get them at the same height as the video. I updated the pen.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?
https://jsfiddle.net/UwGod/f9zda03t/3/

My CSS:

```
body {
  width: 80%;
  margin-inline: auto;
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-inline: 1rem;
  background: green;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  gap: 24px;
  position: relative;
}

.left {
  background: red;
  flex-basis: 20%;
}

.grid {
  display: grid; 
  gap: 24px; 
  grid-template-columns: 0.75fr 0.25fr;
  background: red; 
  flex-grow: 1; 
}

.video {
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center;
  aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
  max-height: calc((100vw * 0.8 - 2rem) * 9 / 16);
}

.chapters {
  background: blue;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: calc((100vw * 0.8 - 2rem) * 9 / 16);
  height: 100%;
}

.chapter_list {
  height: 100%;
}
```

If so, the problem wasn't a `max-height: calc(WHAT IS MY HEIGHT??);` on `.flex`, but on `.chapters` and `.video`.

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't clear enough I guess. The containers surrounding the video will have a undefined number of list items with a fixed height. Now you will see that's not that easy  https://jsfiddle.net/bnzvdore/